# How to take limits in Fourier series?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, fourier-analysis, piecewise

I have a Fourier series which produces an impulse train of period `j+1`. In principle, it is given by

```
f[x_, j_] := (-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*x))/((-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*x)/(1 + j)))*(1 + j))
```

However, this produces `1/0` at integer values of `x` - the limiting value needs to be taken at these points, as the following tables demonstrate:

```
f[x_, j_] := (-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*x))/((-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*x)/(1 + j)))*(1 + j)); 

Table[f[x, j], {x, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]
```

> `{{Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 0, 0,  0, 0}, {Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0}, {Indeterminate,  Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate, 0, 0}, {Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0,  Indeterminate, 0}}`

At present, I get round this by using `Piecewise`:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
f[x_, j_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*x))/((-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*x)/(1 + j)))*(1 + j)), 
   Mod[x, j + 1] != 0}, {1, Mod[x, j + 1] == 0}}]; 
Table[f[x, j], {x, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]
```

> `{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}`

This piecewise definition is clunky, and it gets messy when I start playing around with the function (for example, using `Integrate` - which produces a function that I have have to redefine piecewise).

Ideally, I'd like to *define the function* (the tables are only there as examples) by instructing Mathematica to take the limit at integer `x`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the job:

```
f[x_, j_] := 
  Limit[(-1 + E^(2*I Pi x0))/((-1 + E^((2*I Pi x0)/(1 + j)))*(1 + j)),
    x0 -> x];
Table[f[x, j], {x, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]
```

With this we get:

```
 {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Table[Limit[f[x, j], x -> x0], {x0, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Huber. thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. This would help in the case of the example table I gave, but It's the definition of the function that I'm looking to change.

Comment: Simply define: f[x_, j_] := 
 Limit[(-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*x0))/((-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*x)/(1 + j)))*(1 + j)), 
  x0 -> x]

Comment: Hi @Daniel Huber. Unfortunately, applying this to the example table above produces `{{ComplexInfinity, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {ComplexInfinity, 0, ComplexInfinity, 0, 0, 
  0}, {ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, 0, ComplexInfinity, 0, 
  0}, {ComplexInfinity, 0, 0, 0, ComplexInfinity, 0}}`...

Comment: There is a typo, the second x should read x0:   f[x_, j_] := 
 Limit[(-1 + E^(2*I Pi x0))/((-1 + E^((2*I Pi x0)/(1 + j)))*(1 + j)), x0 -> x];Table[f[x, j], {x, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 5}] ;  With this we get from  Table[f[x, j], {x, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 5}] the result:     {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}

Comment: Hi @Daniel Huber. Do you want to post this as an answer then, and I can mark it up for you?

Comment: O.k. hope this helps.